# Alternatives to scipy's fsolve for underdetermined systems

Tags: scipy, solver, nonlinear-optimization

I have a large nonlinear system with more unknowns than equations and need to find at least some possible roots but scipy's `fsolve` and various solvers through scipy's `root` all complain about mismatch in the input and output vector shapes (or dimensions that are too large). Are there nonlinear solvers in scipy that I can use for underdetermined systems of large dimesion?

Comment: I often use NLP (nonlinear programming) solvers for this. Either just use a dummy objective, or (if the problem is difficult) minimize the sum of the squared deviations or slacks. Note: you need an NLP solver that handles constraints.